# add fragment to a Table of fragments

Tags: sapui5

i have a table in which i need to add the same fragment each time i press add button so basically it is a table of fragments but i'm stack how to add the cell that contains the fragment

```
                      <m:Table id= "table" >
                                <m:headerToolbar>
                                    <m:Toolbar>
                                        <m:content>
                                            <m:Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="addProduct" tooltip="add product" />
                                        </m:content>
                                    </m:Toolbar>
                                </m:headerToolbar>

                                <m:columns>
                                    <m:Column width="12em">
                                    <m:Title text="Results"/>
                                    </m:Column>
                                </m:columns>
                                <m:items>
                                    <m:ColumnListItem>
                                        <m:cells>
                                        <!--    fragments-->
                                        </m:cells>

                                    </m:ColumnListItem>
                                </m:items>
                            </m:Table>
```

i tried with addcell but it doesn't work

help please

Answer (score 0):

With no information on what your fragment contains and what error you get when you try to addcell, it is hard to guess what the problem is.

This is a blind shot, but you could try to wrap your fragment some kinda container, like a vbox etc.
If you add your cell in javascript, try to wrap the content in a new cell befor adding it to the row.

Comment: addFragment:function(){
   var ofrag = sap.ui.xmlfragment("test.view.fragment.addProd");
   var oColumnListItem = new ColumnListItem({
              cells: [
                oFragment
              ]
            });
            this.getView().byId("table").bindItems({
    path: "prodsModel>/Prods",
    template: oColumnListItem
    });
          
  },

Comment: the prob is when i call this function on press add button it only returns one fragment when i press again it doesn't work